# Phaser with mobile resolution

Tags: typescript, mobile, phaser-framework, game-development, pixi.js

My question is how can we separate portrait and landscape mode by designing differently in my mobile view? For example Portrait mode ui and landscape ui is I want it to be different from each other.

I have a game I want to show a different UI in portrait mode when I open it on mobile or I want to show a different UI when I open it in Landscape mode.

For this I prepared the following code block, but it is not correct on every mobile scale. I guess it doesn't make sense to write down the width and height of its all mobiles scale. It must be something automatic.

Game Class

```
public resize(): void {
       
        if (this.game.width > this.game.height) {
            this.game.stage.updateTransform();
            this.elementsPositionLandscape();
        } else {
            this.game.stage.updateTransform();
            this.elementsPositionPortrait();
        }

    }
```

Boot Class

```
this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.USER_SCALE;

        //resize because it's better than any of the phaser provided resizes
        window.addEventListener('resize', (e: Event) => this.mobileResizeCallback(this.game.scale));
        this.game.scale.onSizeChange.add(() => {
            this.game.state.getCurrentState().resize();
        }, this);
        this.mobileResizeCallback(this.game.scale);

public mobileResizeCallback(manager: Phaser.ScaleManager): void {
        let width: number = window.innerWidth;
        let height: number = window.innerHeight;

        let userRatio: number = 1;

        if (width < height) {
            userRatio /= Math.round(height / Constants.GAME_WIDTH * 10) / 10;
        } else {
            userRatio /= Math.round(width / Constants.GAME_WIDTH * 10) / 10;
        }

        let expectedWidh: number = Math.ceil(width * userRatio);
        let expecteHeight: number = Math.ceil(height * userRatio);

        if (manager.width !== expectedWidh || manager.height !== expecteHeight) {
            manager.setGameSize(expectedWidh, expecteHeight);
            manager.setUserScale(1 / userRatio, 1 / userRatio);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. What have you tried? What have you got? Please ensure you include the [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Joshua  I update my description please check thanks!